# Azure Functions - Issues Installing AzureRM Service Bus Module

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use the Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace cmdlet in an Azure Function and running into some issues.

First off, I've uploaded the module via ftp to:

> D:\Home\site\wwwroot\HttpTriggerPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM.ServiceBus\0.4.4\AzureRM.ServiceBus.psm1’

In the Azure Function I specify

```
> Import-Module ‘D:\Home\site\wwwroot\healthcheck\Modules\AzureRM.ServiceBus\0.4.4\AzureRM.ServiceBus.psm1’
```

and try to run Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace I get the following error.

```
> 2017-09-05T07:24:00.049 Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace : The Azure
> PowerShell session has not been properly initialized.  Please import
> the module and try again. at run.ps1: line 19
> + Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace
> + ______________________________
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.Commands.Namespace.GetAzureRmServiceBusNamespace
```

I've tested the module locally and have no issues with running the cmdlet. 
I appreciate any help you can provide,
Thanks!

Comment: Is the `.psd1` a typo in your post? If not, this might be the problem. You need to import the `psm1` file. You have also used 'pretty' quotation marks, which also don't work very well in PowerShell code.

Comment: Thanks for spotting, yep its a typo...